# Why doesn't CSSOM construction wait for Javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

DOM construction waits for javascript execution because javascript has the potential to modify document elements (as well as insert/delete elements). By the same logic, shouldn't CSSOM construction wait for javascript execution because it has the potential to change the styling of elements?

Comment: The CSSOM is derived from the DOM, so why do you think it doesn't wait?

Comment: @Bergi Aren't the CSSOM and DOM independent structures? From my understanding the CSSOM isn't derived from the DOM and can be independently constructed directly from a .css file.

Comment: Yes, but that construction usually happens once the CSS file is added to the DOM of the document you are loading. You were talking about a browser, right?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about a browser. In my mind, the browser engine would spawn a new thread once it reads in the HTML document that a css stylesheet is needed that would request the css file from a remote server and then begin constructing the CSSOM, separate from the "main thread" that is parsing the HTML and building the DOM. Is this not what happens?

Comment: Sure, but reading the HTML document does wait for the JavaScript execution, doesn't it? Even when it uses speculative parsing, the constructed CSSOM won't be applied to the document (and be visible to JS) before the stylesheet element appears in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

No.

JavaScript can modify (through `document.write`) the HTML that is being parsed. This is much more complex than changing the style of an element (or even inserting one with DOM methods).

Repaints due to CSS changes are trivial in comparison.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the reason why CSSOM construction doesn't wait on Javascript is because screen repaints due to JS updating the CSSOM are trivial in comparison to re-layouts due to JS updating the DOM?

Comment: @KevinTan — No. As I said in the answer, it is injections into the incoming HTML stream that need to be handled differently.